# How to upgrade Windows Forms application to .NET 5.0

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I upgraded VS to 16.82.   Then I installed .NET 5.0.

When I choose myproject.sin, it still shows 4.52 as my .Net target Framework and gives 4.7.2 as the highest available.

I went back as myproject now shows as a folder in my list of recent projects. I clicked on it and it came up. Nothing happened when I right clicked myproject (normally it had the page that showed Net framework. I finally clicked on about and it says .NET Framework Version 4.8.04084. Other options are not available on the menu. For example, none of build or publish options are under “Build”.

Could someone tell me what to do?

Comment: [How to migrate a Windows Forms desktop app to .NET 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/migration/)

Comment: You have to migrate projects to .NET 5. .NET 5 is not a next version for .NET Framework 4. Link from first comment has all information.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to actually install .NET 5: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks

Then restart VS and change the targeted .NET version from *Project Properties/Application/Target framework*.

Comment: I have done that.   Still when I go to project properties target framework 4.7.2 is the highest available.   Thanks